# Incorrect mapping between Father and Child tables

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, mapping, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to model a Father/Children relationship in Spring Data JDBC (version 1.1.5.RELEASE). So far i've managed to get the insert operation working, but i'm struck with an error when reading the data.

Entities look like this

```
@Table("FATHER")
data class FatherDao(
    @Id
    val id: Long?, 
    @MappedCollection(idColumn="father_id")
    val childrens: Set<ChildrenDao>
)
```

```
@Table("CHILDREN")
data class ChildrenDao(
    @Id 
    val id: Long?,
    val father: FatherDao?
)
```

Schema is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE father (
   id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1)
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE children (
    id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    father_id INT
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

For now i've omitted Foreign Key on `character_id`.

Repository is simply

```
@Repository
interface FatherRepository : CrudRepository<CharacterDao, Long>
```

For saving children entites associated to the father i do not call a `ChildrenRepository` but instead proceed to save the father entity.

The creation goes smoothly, but when tring to get the created entity i recieve the following exception

```
user lacks privilege or object not found: FATHER.CHILDREN_DAO in statement [SELECT CHILDREN.id AS id, father.id AS father_id FROM CHILDREN LEFT OUTER JOIN FATHER AS father ON father.children_dao = CHILDREN.id WHERE CHILDREN.father_id = ?]
```

My main problem is that i can't undestand where the `FATHER.CHILDREN_DAO` came from. I'm fairly sure it's caused by a bad mapping in the `FatherDao` entity, but even looking in the [Spring Data JDBC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.types) regarding Sets i cannot find a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to try to create a bidirectional relationship between `FatherDao` and `ChildrenDao`.
This is not supported by Spring Data JDBC.
The two connections are considered independent and Spring Data JDBC tries to load the father referenced by a children which according to the mapping rules would require a a `CHILDREN_DAO` on the father.

There are two variants to solve the problem depending on your domain.
The important question is: Are children part of the father aggregate or are they an aggregate on their own?

If **children are part of the father aggregate**, either remove the `father` reference or mark it with `@Transient`.
In the later case you might set the value in the constructor of `FatherDao` or in an [`AfterLoadCallback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/#entity-callbacks)

If **children are their own aggregate** both the `childrens` and the `father` reference should be removed and instead an id (or set of entities containing an id) should be used. 
Instead of the bidirectional relationship you would have query method to load the father of a child or vice versa.

The Article [*Spring Data JDBC, References, and Aggregates*](https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates) explains the reasoning behind this design decision and also has an example how to implement it.

Comment: In my case `children` is part of the `father` aggregate, as it would have little to no meaning as a standalone entity.
Removing the reference did the trick. Thanks for the very detailed explanation and the useful link!